# Basic SPARQL select query breaks randomly in Fuseki/Jena

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I'm not sure how to even approach this problem.  Is it a bug in Fuseki/Jena?

In my 500M+ triple dataset, queries seem to be failing for no clear reason.  Here's an example.

```
prefix Products: <http://www.example.com/test/Products#>  
select ?p ?o
where { 
  <http://www.example.com/test/Products#ABC> ?p ?o .
}
```

...results in a list like:

```
Products:HasComponent Products:DEF
Products:HasComponent Products:GHI
```

Now running this query:

```
prefix Products: <http://www.example.com/test/Products#>  
select ?p
where { 
  <http://www.example.com/test/Products#ABC> ?p Products:DEF .
}
```

...has no results.  How is this possible?

Here's another example:

```
prefix Products: <http://www.example.com/test/Products#>  
ask where { 
  Products:ABC Products:PartNumber ?p .
  filter ( ?p = "ABC" )
}
```

This returns True.

```
prefix Products: <http://www.example.com/test/Products#>  
ask where { 
  ?s Products:PartNumber ?p .
  filter ( ?p = "ABC" )
}
```

This returns False.

Comment: did you try using also <http://www.example.com/test/Products#DEF> instead of Products:DEF? Maybe there is a problem with prefix for some reason.

Comment: This can't happen for sure. Please check your prefixes, i.e. `Products`

Comment: Run the first query without the "prefix" line to see what the URIs really are.